# Exam 70-496: Limit TFS proxy data cache to 15GB

Tags: tfs, tfs-proxy

One of the question in exam 70-496 is about limiting disk usage for cache. What would be the right answer for following question?

**PercentageBasedPolicy** OR **FixedSizeBasedPolicy**

Question is

> You are the administrator of a TFS system that uses version control proxies at remote sites to reduce the burden on the WAN. The hard disk that stores the cache for a version control proxy server is upgraded to a larger size. 
>   Management wants to ensure that more of the disk is used but not all of it.
>   You need to ensure that the proxy always uses a maximum of 15 GB for caching.
>   What should you do?

The link has answer and according to me it should be fixed but various forums says it would be percentage based. Please advise.

Link for Microsoft definition
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400763(v=vs.100).aspxv

Answer (score 3):

**Fixed** the hint is in the "always" and "maximum".

You could probably do it with a percentage one if you know the total disk size, but it's kind of a stupid way of doing it. Unless **Fixed: 15000** is no part of the possible answers.

The size is specified in megabytes.

See also:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400763(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: This is the answer but I am unable to mark this down as answer